# Retrieve current users id from database to use in new tabel

Tags: php, mysql, session, insert

I have a profile page where I retrieve users information.

**Profile.php**

```
  <?php
require 'core/init.php';

if(!$username = Input::get('user')) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
} else {
    $user = new User($username);

    if(!$user->exists()) {
        Redirect::to(404);
    } else {
        $data = $user->data();
    }
    ?>

    <h3><?php echo escape($data->username); ?></h3>
    <p>Membership No: <?php echo escape($data->id); ?></p>
    <p>Full name: <?php echo escape($data->name); ?></p>
    <p>Date of birth: <?php echo escape($data->dob); ?></p>
    <p>Location: <?php echo escape($data->location); ?></p>
    <p>Join date: <?php echo escape($data->joined); ?></p>



    <?php
```

I want to retrieve the id of my user to insert into another table in my order page, so far I have this

**oerder.php**

```
    <?php
session_start();
require 'core/init.php';

$Band_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['band']);
$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id) VALUES('$Band_id', '$user_id')";
mysql_query ($sql, $linkme)
    or die ("could not add to database");
?>
```

currently `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];` is not placing the users id in my table `orders`.

I tried

```
<?php echo escape($data->id); ?>
```

and

```
$user_id = $_GET['id'];
```

but it dose not work, dose anyone know how to retrieve the users `id` so I can insert it into the db?

Comment: What are you seeing on the page?

Comment: Have you dumped the value of $_SESSION['id']? Be sure that is correct

Comment: on the page it works fine but when i check my db the band id is entered but not users id

Comment: What is the type of user_id column? And I am still suspicious about $user_id value. Please check it first.

Comment: the column is id and its a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is save user data to the session

```
$_SESSION['user_data'] = $user->data();
```

you could assign it back to `$data` once you check `$_SESSION['user_data']` is set, else re query the model.

And `session_start()` should also be at the top of every file you want to hold session for.

So something like:

**Profile.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'core/init.php';

if(!$username = Input::get('user')) {
    Redirect::to('index.php');
    exit;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_data'])){
    $user = new User($username);

    if(!$user->exists()) {
        Redirect::to(404);
        exit;
    }

    $_SESSION['user_data'] = $user->data();
}
?>

<h3><?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->username); ?></h3>
<p>Membership No: <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->id); ?></p>
<p>Full name: <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->name); ?></p>
<p>Date of birth: <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->dob); ?></p>
<p>Location: <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->location); ?></p>
<p>Join date: <?php echo escape($_SESSION['user_data']->joined); ?></p>
```

**oerder.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'core/init.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_data'])){
    Redirect::to('index.php');
    exit;
}

$Band_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['band']);
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_data']->id;

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (band_id,user_id) VALUES('$Band_id', '$user_id')";
mysql_query ($sql, $linkme)
or die ("could not add to database");
?>
```

also you should move over to PDO or mysqli.

Comment: `session_start();` must be used inorder to use `$_SESSION`. It uses in order.php. I think `session_autostart` is false

Comment: @Loz Cherone ahh I understand, thank you, I will do some research into PDO

Comment: Ahh Ive discovered a problem, for some reason the order only pics up one user it dose not add different id when new user log's in.